# Anime with birds and a vibrating building

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this as an animated cartoon. I assume from my memory of the style that it was Japanese anime.

The story follows a small group of security personnel dealing, at first, with the problem of industrial robots going berserk and smashing down a line of buildings in the city. The world of the story has mecha suits. As things progress, it is found that all the berserk robots were programmed by a single individual, and they try to find him. At each place they go there are empty bird cages. Eventually, it is determined that the robots are triggered by a certain sound.

The person who programmed the robots also designed a large building in the bay, it is determined that if the wind gets strong enough, the building will vibrate and make the sound and all the robots in the city will go berserk at the same time. Making a situation that is impossible to contain. Due to time constraints, the team is forced to go to the building as a storm builds. They try to destroy the building, but it is too tough. The building is supposed to be empty. But, one member detects motion and life in the penthouse.

They go to investigate, and find a large number of birds (to set off the life monitors) and what amounts to an off-switch. The conclusion being that the person who set all this up wanted to give them an out, only if they cared enough to save the person that they thought was in the penthouse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [*Patlabor: The Movie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patlabor:_The_Movie).

> As Division II goes out on the field, team commander Captain Gotoh,
>   Sgt Asuma Shinohara, and mechanic Shige Shiba work with police
>   Detective Matsui to find further leads on the case. **They discover that
>   all the errant Labors, plus other Labors in the Greater Tokyo Area,
>   were installed with the company's new Hyper Operating System (HOS)
>   software and can be triggered by low-frequency resonance emanating
>   from wind-struck high-rise buildings.** To SV2 pilot Noa Izumi's relief,
>   no copies of the software were installed in Division II's AV98 Ingram
>   police Labors. They also learn that HOS programmer Eiichi Hoba - who
>   committed suicide days before - was obsessed with the Babylon
>   Project's Biblical references (the Ark being alluded to Noah's Ark,
>   for example; his own name. E. Hoba--Jehovah--for another) and planted
>   a self replicating virus in the code that would cause the Labor to
>   malfunction. **A computer simulation predicts that gale-force winds
>   acting on the Ark could send all the Labors in Tokyo into a massive
>   rampage, especially since the Ark's size and steel framework amplifies
>   the resonance frequencies causing them to reach farther into the city.
>   Worse, the weather bureau announces that a typhoon is expected to hit
>   Tokyo within two days.**

Comment: I managed to find several trailers and extracts under that name to verify that this was what I had in mind. Thanks, I have been wondering about that one for years.